# jquery animate left percentage off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to move an image (its a picture of a map) inside its container so a specific part of the image(a city) is in the center of its container when a div is clicked.  I have this working but the percentage that the image moves to the left is less than what I specify while top works fine.

map is the image container and map-img is the image, bad names I am sorry.

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div.scroll {
    position:absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    width: 27%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
div.scroll ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
#map {
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 73%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#map-img {
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="map">
    <img id="map-img" src="images/1842map.png" width="1800" height="2338"/>

</div>

<div class="scroll">
    <ul>
        <!-- Define photos here -->
        <li><img class="tooltipper" id="mepkin" title="Mepkin Plantation" src="images/img1.jpg"/></li>
        <li><a href="mepkin-plantation.html"><p class="image-title">Mepkin Plantation</p></a></li>
        <li><img class="tooltipper" id="biggins" title="Biggins Church" src="images/img2.jpg"/></li>
        <li><p class="image-title">Biggins Church</p></li>            
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".tooltipper").click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('id')==='mepkin'){
            $("#map-img").animate({top: '-47.8%', left: '-10.8%'});   
        }else if ($(this).attr('id')==='biggins'){
            $("#map-img").animate({top: '3.07%', left: '3.70%'});   

    });
    $("#getalertbutton").click(function(){
        var position = $('#map-img').position();
        var percentLeft = position.left/$(window).width() * 100;
        var percentTop = position.top/$(window).height() *100;
        alert("top: "+percentTop+"   "+"left: "+percentLeft);
    }
});
```

When I use the alert to get the percentage that map-img has moved it returns:

Mepkin
top: -47.79
left: -7.88

Biggins
top:-3.069
left:2.69

Since 73% of 10.8 is 7.88 I know that the percentage of the  #map container is the culprit, but I do not know what to do to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work out the percentage? e.g.

```
 $("#map-img").animate({top: '-47.8%', left: '-'+Math.round((10.8/73)*100)+'%'});
```

Comment: I was thinking about this.  Do you think that the issue could be that I have percentages all the way up the DOM?  In other words, since everything is percentage based it will always be different.  Would making the map container pixel-based make this window-size independent?

Comment: Yes, you could set a pixel-based size to avoid this issue. You could also set the map to be 100% and this should also prevent this problem. It all depends on how these things will effect your layout. Don't forget that with media queries you can always set a different width in pixels for different device sizes.

Comment: Awesome thanks I will see what works best for my layout.  I appreciate the  advice.